# how can I make a Inline calendar using bootstrap, javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a index.html file. I want to create a inline calendar using bootstrap.But I am getting an error called "VM1487:3 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function".I donot know good bootstrap, javascript.please help me someone,Here is my code:

/index.html

```
<div class="form-group all-forms">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-5 r-view">
    <div id="datetimepicker"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,
            sideBySide: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you included js script of datepicker?

Comment: you may need https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/

Answer (score 1):

You are using `datetimepicker` while it should be `datepicker`. As per the docs. Try this and it should work. Make sure include right css and right js.

These are the css and js files for datetimepicker that must be included before use with jquery and bootstrap js:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
              // your options
            });
          });
</script>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where to add these two link and how to link. I do not have any Idea. please help me

Comment: can I write like this  <script src=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>                    <style ><link rel=" https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.37/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" > </style>   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
          // your options
        });
      });
     </script>

Comment: wait. I made a mistake.

Comment: @Roy Now try this.

Comment: @Roy Yes you can.